# Changes in app/design/frontend/Theme/theme/.../Magento_Newsletter not updating

Tags: magento2, newsletter, design

I am trying to update some of the pages on my site and have navigated to:

```
app/design/frontend/Meigee/hoker/Magento_Newsletter
```

I am then editing a file called `subscribe.phtml`

However, any changes I make are not updated on my site even after flushing all cache.

PATH:

```
app\design\frontend\Meigee\hoker\Magento_Newsletter\templates\subscribe.phtml
```

Any help?

Comment: please show your file path where you have keep subscribe.phtml file

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I have added this for you.